# Obtener últimos 15 elementos de un array

Tags: javascript

Tengo un array de una dimensión, de `length` variable, pero siempre mayor a 15. ¿Cómo puedo hacerle para obtener los últimos 15 elementos de este?

Vi que puedo usar `slice`, y que se tienen que usar números negativos, pero simplemente no logro hacer que funcione como necesito.

Intenté con

```
let arreglo15 = arreglo.slice(-1 * arreglo.length, -1 * (arreglo.length - 15));
```

Y con

```
let arreglo15 = arreglo.slice(-1 * arreglo.length, 15);
```

Necesito que lo obtenido (`array15`) sea un array. Por eso estoy usando el método `slice`.

Comment: Puedes leer la cantidad total de registros y hacer un bucle en retroceso, desde ese ultimo registro hasta esa variable -15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba así, creo que es lo que pides
El array.slice te devuelve un array desde el índice que le indicas hasta el final(si no le indicas el indice de final) o hasta el que le indiques el último registro que quieres(no cuenta el índice del último).
Solo tienes que decirle que quieres de inicio la longitud total - 15 elementos y te dará los 15 últimos.

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

console.log(array.slice(array.length - 15))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let aNumeros = [1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12];

let aNuevo  = aNumeros.slice(aNumeros.length-5);

console.log(aNuevo);
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! Sabia que la respuesta era sencilla, pero no estoy carburando bien en estos momento 

Comment: No olvides explicar el funcionamiento del código: recuerda que la respuesta debe ser útil no solo para el OP (autor de la pregunta), sino también para otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema más adelante. Puede que otros usuarios no comprendan su funcionamiento, y no es bueno limitarse al  _copypaste_. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta, y lee [answer].